# How nanorobots are programmed?

Tags: robotics-toolbox

I was thinking about the possible ways to program nanorobots, it can't be done with the regular tools.So I'm curious to know how professionals program nanobots?
Any complementary articles, extra readings are welcomed.

Comment: which nanobots are you talking about?

Comment: @jsotola I'm talking in general, for example, nanobots in medicine. How they are being programmed?

Comment: you are talking like they are in widespread use

Comment: Yeah they aren't for now, but my question is how?? How materials in nano/micro scale are programmed if they are any of them available now in real usage?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user668687, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having the same question, I have found the answer :

---

> The development of programmable nanobot arch-types offers an
> opportunity to consider tools for programming nanobot cocktails.
> Inspired by modern software development environments, which separates
> high-level programming languages from specific CPU details, we aim to
> allow medical professionals to directly program treatments in Athelas,
> a medication programming language.  the design of Athelas is
> motivated by  the  success  of  rule-based  systems  at  capturing
> expert  knowledge  [6,  7].   A  compiler  (Bilbo)  translates Athelas
> programs to nanobot specifications, which implement the program.  The
> compiler relies on a library of generic nanobot arch-types, and
> specializes them to create the specific roles needed for the swarm.

---

Reference: *[A Compiler for Programming Molecular Robots](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Egalk/Publications/papers/fnano16.pdf) Inbal Wiesel, Noa Agmon, and Gal A. Kaminka*